# Using PFQueryForTableViewController and capturing information for segue at table cell

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uitableview, parse-platform

so I am using a `PFQueryForTableViewController` class connected to my storyboard. I use the `queryForTable` method to get the information in the back, but the information is in a different order every time that the user queries for the table. When the user presses on the cell it segues to another viewController. I need to retain the information at that cell when the user presses the cell to fill in the information on the next view controller. I am currently using the `tableView: didSelectRowAtIndexPath: object:` method, as well as the `prepareForSegue:` method. I am not sure how to retain the information, and with the code I am currently running, I am getting the error:

`"'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UITableViewCell objectAtIndex:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x9b6e420'"`

Here is the code for the segue:

```
- (void) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    [super tableView:tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];

    self.selectedCell = indexPath;
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"profile" sender:[self.objectId objectAtIndex:self.selectedCell.row]];


}

- (void) prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {

    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"profile"]) {
        ProfileViewController *userInfo = [segue destinationViewController];
        userInfo.userInfo = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:sender];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Using sender for passing this information is not good practice. Instead, I would use a private property in the table view and setting this when you select the row.

In didSelectRowAtIndexPath:

```
self.currentProfile = [self objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];
[self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"profile" sender:self];
```

Then, in prepareForSegue:

```
ProfileViewController *userInfo = [segue destinationViewController];
userInfo.user = self.currentProfile; // Or, if you want to pass user details as array, create array here
```

Comment: Did you get anywhere on this, @user3159704 ?